# Why does the modulus of $x$ become $-x$ as $x$ tends to negative infinity in this example?

Tags: calculus, limits

I came across this example in Thomas' calculus:

For $x>0$:
$$
\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{x^3-2}{|x|^3+1}=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x^3-2}{(-x)^3+1}
$$

I was always taught that the modulus of $x$ will always be positive, but here it has been made negative and I am not sure as to what the mathematical reasoning behind doing this is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(the full example is on page 105 of Thomas'Calculus: early transcendentals)

Comment: If $x<0$, then $-x$ is positive, so $|x|=-x$.

Comment: When $x$ is negative, $|x| = -x$ is positive. Don't be misled by the minus sign in front of the $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The part “for $x>0$” makes no sense, if you want to compute the limit for $x\to-\infty$.

But, since you're interested in this limit, it is not restrictive to assume $x<0$, so $|x|=-x$ (which is indeed positive).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna know how limit is negative then let me tell you that for $x<0$ then $|x|=-x$

> Proof - $|x|$ will result in $x$ and $-x$. However since $x<0$, $x$ case is eliminated and so $|x|=-x$

Answer (score 0):

When computing a limit of the form $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)$, you can assume that $x<0$. This is because, by definition, $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=l$ means

> For every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $N>0$ such that $x<-N \implies|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.

Since $N>0$, we have $-N<0$, and so $x<-N<0$. Thus, we are only interested in the behaviour of $f(x)$ when $x$ is negative. So to compute
$$
\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{x^3-2}{|x|^3+1}
$$
we can assume that $x<0$, and so $|x|=-x$ (remembering that $-x$ is *positive* in this case).

As Egreg has already noted, it doesn't make sense to say

> For $\color{red}{x>0}$:
> $$
> \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{x^3-2}{|x|^3+1}=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x^3-2}{(-x)^3+1}
> $$

and so I'm assuming that you meant to say "for $\color{red}{x<0}$" instead.